# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:0)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14

I'm trying to add FULLCALENDAR to my Angular v14 project.

But after all setup suddenly I'm facing this error

Any idea how to deal with this error?

**package.json**

```
"@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.11.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.0",
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([ // register FullCalendar plugins
dayGridPlugin,
interactionPlugin
]);

imports:[
      ...
      FullCalendarModule
     ]
```

**Throw error**

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.css 4:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* classes attached to <body> */
| /* TODO: make fc-event selector work when calender in shadow DOM */
> .fc-not-allowed,
| .fc-not-allowed .fc-event { /* override events' custom cursors */
|   cursor: not-allowed;


ERROR in ./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css 2:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
> :root {
|   --fc-daygrid-event-dot-width: 8px;
| }
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a workaround but its not good at all, hope they will fix it as soon as possible

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/403#issuecomment-1149834448

i recommend to add this to the angular.json

```
"styles" : [
...
"./node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.css",
"./node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css",
"./node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css",
"./node_modules/@fullcalendar/list/main.css",
...
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Use version ^6.0.0-beta.1 or higher..